# C# LibVLC, Mostly gray frames first 2 sec. Decoding error?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, libvlc

I currently have a very nice working videoplayer using libVLC and Xamarin.Forms. The only small problem I have is that I currently get 1 or 2 sec of the screen being mostly gray when starting a video. I think this has to do with the decoding in some way, because currently only the changes in the video will give it color, something like a cut or seeking the video will compleatly clear the effect.

Is there a way to clear the current frame without seeking the media or some other way to remove this small issue? Is it some function I forgot to call?

Currently I am playing the file via

```cs
disMedia = new Media(_libVLC, currentVideo.downloadFileUrl, FromType.FromPath, options.ToArray());
vvideo.MediaPlayer.Play(disMedia);
```

where options are "start-time={startTime}"

(This is a 20s long yt clip that will show the current gray *bug* when opening a file: https://youtu.be/ck4f02VBDnk )

Comment: @Greg Im sorry, just felt like a 20s long yt video would explain the situation in a good way. You can obviously see that the issue has to do with inital loading and I thought showing an example whould clear up any misunderstanding about the topic. The video was only meant to be additive to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the video, it's indeed useful to understand the issue. Please provide full code next time. Readers have no idea what libvlc version you use, or what device, etc...

Comment: seems like a hardware decoding error. I ought to push a libvlc update on nuget anyway..

Comment: @mfkl o im sorry, I like to stay as updated as possible, I use libvlc 3.4.7 and the video is recorded on android 9 (Target API 28: android 9.0, min API 25: android 5.0). I get it both with and without EnableHardwareDecoding. Some users of my app reported this bug, and I also have it, so I cant exactly say if it is only on some specific version of android/hardware. Full sourcecode it on Github, but it is very long and not of good quality: https://github.com/LagradOst/CloudStream-2/blob/18172407b023ce4d43edc272817c19866ccf58e4/CloudStreamForms/CloudStreamForms/Pages/VideoPage.xaml.cs#L1384

Comment: Any video has this problem?

Comment: I cant say with 100% certainty this is the case, but all the downloaded files I tested via libvlc had the gray bug. The exact same videos played in vlc android had no issues. It might be that I play the file the exact same frame as _libvlc and videoplayer is created, but I dont know. I can do some futher testing today.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. For some reason calling vvideo.MediaPlayer.Play([media]) the same frame it is created will make it gray for the first 2 sec or so. Just adding `await Task.Delay(1);` and making the load method async will compleatly remove this. The only problem is that it takes 1s or so to load the video, even if the delay is only for 1ms.

Comparing the results from adding await Task.Delay(1); and not. I get 500-1400ms compared to 10ms. With the gray bug I get instant loading of the video, but with Delay 1ms, I get 1s loading. This looks very similar to vlc for android, having a compleatly dark screen for 0.5s-1.5s when loading a downloaded video. Is this another bug? I feel like the loading should be instant, like it was before with the gray bug.

This is very confusing, and I dont really know if this is the prefered solution to solving this.